# Bottom Navigation Activity with external button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Bottom Navigation Activity from Android Studio

[image]

After setting all the needed bottom tabs, I need to add aditional button for one fragment, but outside the tab zone. And that button is only when the second fragment is called.
Something like in image below

[image]

I've set new fragment in navigation/mobile_navigation.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_demografski"
    android:name="com.home.Fragment1"
    android:label="Podaci o osobama"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_biometrijski"
    android:name="com.home.Fragment2"
    android:label="Biometrijski podaci - Desna Ruka"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_biometrijski2"
    android:name="com.home.Fragment3"
    android:label="Biometrijski podaci - Lijeva Ruka"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard2" />
```

But I don't know how to call the third fragment from the second fragment.
I tried to use `fragmet.replace()` but it just overlaps one fragment over the other.

Tabbed activity

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_demografski, R.id.navigation_biometrijski).build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` as fragment container, then switch fragments inside it. You could do that by setting `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to `BottomNavigationView` and using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, selectedFragment).commit();
```

to switch between the fragments. On mentioned button in second fragment add `onClickListener` and call previous transaction from `Activity` with desired fragment as selectedFragment

Answer (score 0):

you can implement by following my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //loading the default fragment
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance to edit the current generated code withount doint everything from scratch. I would like to understand how to edit this Android Studio generated code. Thanks